# Group by and Add a New Element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add a New Element nesting P01,P02 and P03 inside of `<Position></Position>`. Once in this new element I need them to group by and sort by PositionNo, Please see sample source and expected result XML.

Source XML Below:

```
  <PO1>
    <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
    <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
    <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
    <PositionNo>1</PositionNo>
    <ArticleNo>148756833112</ArticleNo>
    <QuantityLoading></QuantityLoading>
    <LMSM></LMSM>
    <QuantityUnit1>300000</QuantityUnit1>
    <UnitLevel>1</UnitLevel>
    <Obsolete1></Obsolete1>
    <Obsolete2></Obsolete2>
    <NetWeight>105600</NetWeight>
    <GrossWeight>105600</GrossWeight>
    <WeightUnit></WeightUnit>
    <ArticleDamageStatusFlag>0</ArticleDamageStatusFlag>
    <CustomStatusFlag>F</CustomStatusFlag>
    <PickingAdvice></PickingAdvice>
    <StockManagementFlag></StockManagementFlag>
    <LoadingNo></LoadingNo>
    <MeansOfTransportNo></MeansOfTransportNo>
    <StockNo>STANDARD</StockNo>
    <PackageId></PackageId>
    <PosIndex>101</PosIndex>
    <LMSMID></LMSMID>
    <Unit1Factor>1000</Unit1Factor>
    <Volume>0</Volume>
    <VolumeUnit>CBM</VolumeUnit>
    <LMSMQtyFactor></LMSMQtyFactor>
    <MeasurementUnitLevel></MeasurementUnitLevel>
    <MeasurementName></MeasurementName>
    <MeasurementUnit>1</MeasurementUnit>
    <PercentalExcessDelivery></PercentalExcessDelivery>
    <SmallestIndivisibleUnit></SmallestIndivisibleUnit>
    <AccuracyOfQty></AccuracyOfQty>
    <MTQQty></MTQQty>
    <PackingInstruction></PackingInstruction>
    <PickingListReference></PickingListReference>
  </PO1>
  <P02>
    <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
    <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
    <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
    <PositionNo>1</PositionNo>
    <LotNo></LotNo>
    <ArticleNoRecipient></ArticleNoRecipient>
    <ExternalReference></ExternalReference>
    <PositionText1></PositionText1>
    <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
    <ProductionDate></ProductionDate>
    <ProductionTime></ProductionTime>
    <FreeSlotSelectionFlag></FreeSlotSelectionFlag>
    <CustomerOrderNo></CustomerOrderNo>
    <OrderPositionNo></OrderPositionNo>
    <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
    <ExternalReference2></ExternalReference2>
    <PosIndex>101</PosIndex>
    <Price1>0</Price1>
    <Price2>0</Price2>
    <Document></Document>
    <ArticleVariantNumber></ArticleVariantNumber>
    <SetType></SetType>
    <DestinyStock></DestinyStock>
    <CurrencyPrice1></CurrencyPrice1>
    <CurrencyPrice2></CurrencyPrice2>
    <PrintLanguage></PrintLanguage>
    <ArticleGroup></ArticleGroup>
    <LatestShippingDate></LatestShippingDate>
    <ExpirationDate></ExpirationDate>
    <ShelfLife></ShelfLife>
    <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
  </P02>
  <P03>
    <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
    <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
    <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
    <PositionNo>1</PositionNo>
    <PositionText2></PositionText2>
    <PositionText3></PositionText3>
    <PosIndex>101</PosIndex>
    <EAN></EAN>
  </P03>
  <PO1>
    <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
    <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
    <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
    <PositionNo>2</PositionNo>
    <ArticleNo>180030550211</ArticleNo>
    <QuantityLoading></QuantityLoading>
    <LMSM></LMSM>
    <QuantityUnit1>200000</QuantityUnit1>
    <UnitLevel>1</UnitLevel>
    <Obsolete1></Obsolete1>
    <Obsolete2></Obsolete2>
    <NetWeight>640000</NetWeight>
    <GrossWeight>640000</GrossWeight>
    <WeightUnit></WeightUnit>
    <ArticleDamageStatusFlag>0</ArticleDamageStatusFlag>
    <CustomStatusFlag>F</CustomStatusFlag>
    <PickingAdvice></PickingAdvice>
    <StockManagementFlag></StockManagementFlag>
    <LoadingNo></LoadingNo>
    <MeansOfTransportNo></MeansOfTransportNo>
    <StockNo>STANDARD</StockNo>
    <PackageId></PackageId>
    <PosIndex>201</PosIndex>
    <LMSMID></LMSMID>
    <Unit1Factor>1000</Unit1Factor>
    <Volume>35945</Volume>
    <VolumeUnit>CBM</VolumeUnit>
    <LMSMQtyFactor></LMSMQtyFactor>
    <MeasurementUnitLevel></MeasurementUnitLevel>
    <MeasurementName></MeasurementName>
    <MeasurementUnit>1</MeasurementUnit>
    <PercentalExcessDelivery></PercentalExcessDelivery>
    <SmallestIndivisibleUnit></SmallestIndivisibleUnit>
    <AccuracyOfQty></AccuracyOfQty>
    <MTQQty></MTQQty>
    <PackingInstruction></PackingInstruction>
    <PickingListReference></PickingListReference>
  </PO1>
  <P02>
    <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
    <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
    <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
    <PositionNo>2</PositionNo>
    <LotNo></LotNo>
    <ArticleNoRecipient></ArticleNoRecipient>
    <ExternalReference></ExternalReference>
    <PositionText1></PositionText1>
    <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
    <ProductionDate></ProductionDate>
    <ProductionTime></ProductionTime>
    <FreeSlotSelectionFlag></FreeSlotSelectionFlag>
    <CustomerOrderNo></CustomerOrderNo>
    <OrderPositionNo></OrderPositionNo>
    <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
    <ExternalReference2></ExternalReference2>
    <PosIndex>201</PosIndex>
    <Price1>0</Price1>
    <Price2>0</Price2>
    <Document></Document>
    <ArticleVariantNumber></ArticleVariantNumber>
    <SetType></SetType>
    <DestinyStock></DestinyStock>
    <CurrencyPrice1></CurrencyPrice1>
    <CurrencyPrice2></CurrencyPrice2>
    <PrintLanguage></PrintLanguage>
    <ArticleGroup></ArticleGroup>
    <LatestShippingDate></LatestShippingDate>
    <ExpirationDate></ExpirationDate>
    <ShelfLife></ShelfLife>
    <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
  </P02>
  <P03>
    <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
    <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
    <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
    <PositionNo>2</PositionNo>
    <PositionText2></PositionText2>
    <PositionText3></PositionText3>
    <PosIndex>201</PosIndex>
    <EAN></EAN>
  </P03>
```

Here you can see the sample expected result sorted and grouped under the new element Position.

```
    <Position>
      <PO1>
        <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
        <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
        <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
        <PositionNo>1</PositionNo>
        **ETC.**
      </P01>
      <PO2>
        <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
        <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
        <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
        <PositionNo>1</PositionNo>
        **ETC.**
      </P02>
      <PO3>
        <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
        <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
        <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
        <PositionNo>1</PositionNo>
        **ETC.**
      </P03>
    </Position>
    <Position>
      <PO1>
        <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
        <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
        <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
        <PositionNo>2</PositionNo>
        **ETC.**
      </P01>
      <PO2>
        <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
        <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
        <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
        <PositionNo>2</PositionNo>
         **ETC.**
      </P02>
      <PO3>
        <ClientNo>ABCD</ClientNo>
        <OrderNo>10000014</OrderNo>
        <FunctionNo>10</FunctionNo>
        <PositionNo>2</PositionNo>
      </P03>
    </Position>
```

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info). Note that methods are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the link Michael, to be honest I am quite poor at XSLT. I will go through the link and see if it gets me sorted, I have found another way to achieve this but I am keen to learn how to get this right.

Comment: Well, *grouping* is probably the most often asked XSLT question here, so there are plenty of examples. If you run into an obstacle, you can post your attempt to get help (make sure to state which version of XSLT your processor supports).